# Как получить значение input?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    
  
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
   <div class="container calculate">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                <h2>За сколько месяцев окупится<br>установка <span style="color:rgb(89, 190, 224);">ГБО?</span></h2>
                <br>
                <form action="" id="form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="     Введите марку авто" id="input1" required> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button_first" style="height:50px;">Далее</button>
                </form>

                <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h3 style="color:rgb(89, 190, 224);margin-top:20px;" class="text-center">Расчет успешно завершен!</h3> 
                        <br>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                               <h3>Окупаемость и экономия</h5>    
                                <br>
                                <p>Стоимость установки <span id="price"></span></p>
                                <p>Окупаемость системы <span id="payback">4 км</span></p>
                                <p>Экономия в год <span id="economy_year">4 грн</span></p>
                                <p>Экономия в день <span id="economy_day">4 грн</span></p>
                                <p>Экономия с 1км пути <span id="economy_km">4 грн</span></p>     
                                <br>
                                <h4>На 100грн вы проедете</h4>  
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="oil_bar">192км на бензине</div>
                                  </div> 
                                  <br>
                                  <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="gas_bar">329км на газе</div>
                                  </div> 
                                  <br>
                        </div>  
                        
                        <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top:50px;">
                          <h4 id="economy_year">
                            Оставьте заяку на бесплатную консультацию
                          </h4>
                          <p>
                            Расскажем про особенности установки,виды комплетаций и ответим на ваши вопросы
                          </p>
                            <form action="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="ГБО">
                                <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="admin@mail.com">
                                <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Form Subject">
                                <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->
                            
                                <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="     Имя" required><br><br>
                                <input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="     Телефон" required><br><br>
                                
                              <button class="btn btn-primary">Оставить заявку</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>    
                        
                                       
                      </div>
                      
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                
                
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6">
               <img src="work/image.png" alt="" width="90%" height="100%">
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
   
    <!-- Подключаем jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Подключаем плагин Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Подключаем Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js">
    
</script>
   
    
</body>
</html>
```

> Проблема заключается в том, что при попытке присвоить переменной price значение, посредством if, значение price всегда равно 26000

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button_first');
let input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
let form = document.getElementById('form');

var btn2 = document.createElement('button');
var input2 = document.createElement('input');

let input3 = document.createElement('input');
let btn3 = document.createElement('button');

let input4 = document.createElement('input');
let btn4 = document.createElement('button');

let input5 = document.createElement('input');
let btn5 = document.createElement('button');

let input6 = document.createElement('input');
let btn6 = document.createElement('button');

let input7 = document.createElement('input');
let btn7 = document.createElement('button');

let btn8 = document.createElement('button');

var price_field = document.getElementById('price');
var price = 0;

 var price_field = document.getElementById('price');


 if(input2.value == "3" || "4" ){
  var price = 13500;
 }
   if(input2.value == "5" || "6"){
  var price = 26000;
 }


//step 1
function step1(){
 if (!Element.prototype.remove) {
  Element.prototype.remove = function remove() {
   if (input1.parentNode) {
    input1.parentNode.removeChild(input1);
   }
   if (button.parentNode) {
    button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
   }
  };
 }
 
 
 input1.remove();
 button.remove();

 
 input2.setAttribute('placeholder','     Введите кол-во цилиндров');
 form.appendChild(input2);



 btn2.innerHTML = "Далее"
 btn2.style = "margin-left:5px"
 btn2.classList.add('btn');
 btn2.classList.add('btn-primary');
 btn2.classList.add('button_first');
 form.appendChild(btn2);
 
}
button.addEventListener('click',step1);



function step2(){
 


 
 if (!Element.prototype.remove) {
  Element.prototype.remove = function remove() {
   if (input2.parentNode) {
   input2.parentNode.removeChild(input2);
   }
   if (btn2.parentNode) {
    btn2.parentNode.removeChild(btn2);
   }
  };
 }
 
 
 
 input2.remove();
 btn2.remove();

 
 input3.setAttribute('placeholder','     Мощность двигателя');
 form.appendChild(input3);

 
 btn3.innerHTML = "Далее"
 btn3.style = "margin-left:5px"
 btn3.classList.add('btn');
 btn3.classList.add('btn-primary');
 btn3.classList.add('button_first');
 form.appendChild(btn3);
 
}
btn2.addEventListener('click',step2);

function step3(){
 if (!Element.prototype.remove) {
  Element.prototype.remove = function remove() {
   if (input3.parentNode) {
    input3.parentNode.removeChild(input2);
   }
   if (btn3.parentNode) {
    btn3.parentNode.removeChild(btn2);
   }
  };
 }
 
 
 input3.remove();
 btn3.remove();
 

 
 input4.setAttribute('placeholder','     Средний расход бензина на 100км');
 form.appendChild(input4);

 
 btn4.innerHTML = "Далее"
 btn4.style = "margin-left:5px"
 btn4.classList.add('btn');
 btn4.classList.add('btn-primary');
 btn4.classList.add('button_first');
 form.appendChild(btn4);
 
}
btn3.addEventListener('click',step3);

function step4(){
 if (!Element.prototype.remove) {
  Element.prototype.remove = function remove() {
   if (input4.parentNode) {
    input4.parentNode.removeChild(input4);
   }
   if (btn4.parentNode) {
    btn4.parentNode.removeChild(btn4);
   }
  };
 }
 
 
 input4.remove();
 btn4.remove();

 
 input5.setAttribute('placeholder','     Средний суточнiй пробег');
 form.appendChild(input5);

 
 btn5.innerHTML = "Далее"
 btn5.style = "margin-left:5px"
 btn5.classList.add('btn');
 btn5.classList.add('btn-primary');
 btn5.classList.add('button_first');
 form.appendChild(btn5);
 
}
btn4.addEventListener('click',step4);


function step5(){
 if (!Element.prototype.remove) {
  Element.prototype.remove = function remove() {
   if (input5.parentNode) {
    input5.parentNode.removeChild(input5);
   }
   if (btn5.parentNode) {
    btn5.parentNode.removeChild(btn5);
   }
  };
 }
 
 
 input5.remove();
 btn5.remove();

 
 input6.setAttribute('placeholder','     Стоимость 1л бензина');
 form.appendChild(input6);

 
 btn6.innerHTML = "Далее"
 btn6.style = "margin-left:5px"
 btn6.classList.add('btn');
 btn6.classList.add('btn-primary');
 btn6.classList.add('button_first');
 form.appendChild(btn6);
 
}
btn5.addEventListener('click',step5);

function step6(){
 if (!Element.prototype.remove) {
  Element.prototype.remove = function remove() {
   if (input6.parentNode) {
    input6.parentNode.removeChild(input6);
   }
   if (btn6.parentNode) {
    btn6.parentNode.removeChild(btn6);
   }
  };
 }
 
 
 input6.remove();
 btn6.remove();

 
 input7.setAttribute('placeholder','     Стоимость 1л газа');
 form.appendChild(input7);

 btn7.setAttribute('data-target','.bd-example-modal-xl');
 btn7.setAttribute('data-toggle','modal');
 btn7.innerHTML = "Далее"
 btn7.style = "margin-left:5px"
 btn7.classList.add('btn');
 btn7.classList.add('btn-primary');
 btn7.classList.add('button_first');
 form.appendChild(btn7);
 price_field.innerHTML = price + "грн";
 
}
btn6.addEventListener('click',step6);



function step7(){
 if (!Element.prototype.remove) {
  Element.prototype.remove = function remove() {
   if (input7.parentNode) {
    input7.parentNode.removeChild(input7);
   }
   if (btn7.parentNode) {
    btn7.parentNode.removeChild(btn7);
   }
  };
 }
 
 
 input7.remove();
 btn7.remove();

 
 

 
 btn8.setAttribute('data-target','.bd-example-modal-xl');
 btn8.setAttribute('data-toggle','modal');
 btn8.innerHTML = "Посмотреть результат"
 btn8.style = "margin-left:5px"
 btn8.classList.add('btn');
 btn8.classList.add('btn-primary');
 btn8.classList.add('button_first');
 form.appendChild(btn8);
 
}
btn7.addEventListener('click',step7);
```

Comment: Если ты добавишь воспроизводимый пример кода то вероятность получить ответ будет больше. И не стоит 2 раза использовать if для проверки одного значения. Надо использовать elseif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя за один раз сравнить сразу с несколькими значениями.

В таком виде

```
input2.value == "3" || "4"
```

значение инпута будет сравнено с `"3"`, и если оно ему не равно будет возвращено `"4"`, что внутри `if` будет расценено как `true`.

Аналогично и со следующим условием.

Вместо этого сравнение нужно добавлять каждый раз:

```
input2.value == "3" || input2.value == "4"
```